# AM_CONDITIONAL testing size of type

Tags: autoconf, automake

I would like to define `PLATFORM64` if `SIZEOF_VOIDP` equals 8, the configure snippet below don't work but shows what I would like to achieve. Is there a way of doing this in my configure script?

```
# Get size of void*
AC_CHECK_SIZEOF(void*)

# Determine if this is a 32 or 64 bit system, this can also be set manually with "-DPLATFORM64"
AM_CONDITIONAL([PLATFORM64], [test SIZEOF_VOIDP = 8])
```

**Update:**

I've tried:

```
AM_CONDITIONAL([PLATFORM64], [test "$SIZEOF_VOIDP" -eq 8])
```

but I get "test: bad number" error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `AC_CHECK_SIZEOF` is defining a preprocessor directive, not setting a shell variable. You could try testing `$host_cpu` after calling `AC_CANONICAL_HOST`.

Alternatively:

```
AC_PREPROC_IFELSE([AC_LANG_SOURCE([
#if SIZEOF_VOIDP != 8
#error
#endif
])], [platform64=true], [platform64=false])

AM_CONDITIONAL([PLATFORM64], [test "$platform64" = true])
```

Comment: Tried it now but `PLATFORM64` was not set.

Comment: Well pastebin an error message or the output of config.log or your configure.ac or something because I'm not psychic.

Comment: There is a lot of spam in that log, but might it be some of these? `Checking sizeof void*. Result: 8. conftest.cpp:40: error: expected unqualifier-id before string constant. conftest.cpp:58: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before ';' token. PLATFORM64_FALSE='#'. PLATFORM64_TRUE=''. `

Comment: Possibly. Can you pastebin your configure.ac?